# Show a drop down list below the edit text when edit text changes

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an edit text for entering the location and based on the results of the google places API I have to show them in a dropdown list below the edit text.
Unable to figure out how to create a down list below the edit text.
Attaching image for reference

**Sample image**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to use [AutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html), add some API results adapter and refresh its content when any letter enters into `EditText` (use `TextWatcher`)

from `AutoCompleteTextView`s doc:

> An editable text view that shows completion suggestions automatically while the user is typing. The list of suggestions is displayed in a drop down menu from which the user can choose an item to replace the content of the edit box with.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve your design

**In XML**

```
 <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/id_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/enter_building_or_street_address"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/id_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

**In Class**

- Implement `TextWatcher` for the `EditText`
- onTextChanged - **call place api** and list the response on
  `recyclerview` if response is not null